# How to convert string into bytes in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert the string into bytes and the string doesn't exceed more than 2 bytes.

Can any one give me an idea how to convert the string to bytes and checking it not exceeding 2 bytes.

Comment: It's pretty simple. So simple that we think you should read the NSString.h spec before asking here. There's a method to get a C string from and NSString. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the method **cStringUsingEncoding:** in [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class.